# Multiprocessing throws an OS error, but still gives a result?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a django application that will work as a hub for analyzing data taken for Castor EDC.  I am currently working on a function which will make several API requests to their server to pull the data for analysis, but my original code was VERY slow. So I'm trying now to introduce some multiprocessing, but I'm pretty new to this concept being used in Python instead of R. I'm getting an error that seems to repeat itself over and over again until the operation is complete. The weird thing is that it seems to work other than throwing this OS error. Any idea what I can do to solve this?

I made sure that there are no named files in the directory that contain characters other than [a-z] or [0-9] other than what is given by the Django set up. I don't think I should remove that since it allows files to be treated as modules? I also made sure to use if **name** == '**main**', but still get the error. There is also no references to files with weird names.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import ast
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_data(id,bearer):
   #Make API request from web server.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(4):
        c = get_data(id, bearer)
```

The IDE prints the following over and over again until the operations are complete:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'path\\<input>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)    
prepare(preparation_data)  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
        _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
  File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
```

Here is the contents of the folder:

```
os.listdir()

['.idea', 'CTMS', 'dataAnalysis', 'db.sqlite3', 'fileManager', 'manage.py', '__init__.py']

I get my desired result except the above error code prints repeatedly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no multiprocessing invoked. You have just created the pool with 4 cpu cores, using mp.Pool(4), but you have not used it. There are different methods like

> map(), map_async(), apply(), apply_async(), starmap()

in mp.Pool() which allows it to go under multiprocessing.

Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html for better understanding of mp.Pool() workings.

About the error, its not finding a valid path, from as much error it is showing.I am unable to reproduce the code from this code snippet. So make sure, you use the multiprocessing first and then if problem persists, comment to this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll admit I didn't take much time to go through the documentation. I rewrote my data request function and pass a list of urls to use the map method as you listed.